# Why is less acting like cat?

Tags: bash, less-unix

I've been searching and testing for hours.  I finally found that less paginates if it is called from the main body of the bash script.  But it acts like cat if called from a function or inside {}.  I've tried pipes and also using a temporary file.

I tried a test script without tee to a logfile and it worked OK. With the {}, less did not paginate. Maybe I need a better way to save the script output. I'm using "less -R" because it is going to use color diff.

```
#!/bin/bash
#

tryit()
{
    longfile=$(mktemp)
    /bin/ls -R /etc 2>/dev/null > $longfile

    less -R $longfile
}

{
    tryit
} 2>&1 | tee SOME_LOGFILE
```

Comment: I know that your question seems straightforward, but providing sample code of what isn't working could prove useful.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour. You need to make a [mre]. I tried this and it worked fine: `f(){ less "$@"; }; f ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Programs can't tell if they were called from a function or the main body of the script. However, `less` changes its behavior depending on whether stdout is a terminal; it only makes sense to paginate when displaying on a terminal. Are you redirecting when you call the function?

Comment: Well... that worked as expected. :( `#!/bin/bash
#

tryit()
{
        longfile=$(mktemp)
        /bin/ls -R /etc 2>/dev/null > $longfile

        less -R $longfile
}

tryit
`

Comment: The problem is exactly what I said above: You're piping the output of `less` to `tee`. If it did pagination, `SOME_LOGFILE` would contain all the terminal escape sequences for going back and forth in the file.

Comment: If that's what you want, use `script` rather than piping to `tee`.

Comment: Thanks!  I'lll try script when I have a chance.  I thought the output would still go to stdout with tee but removing the pipe to tee fixed it.

Comment: "unbuffer -p less ..." fixed the problem.  But I switched to vimdiff.  Thanks

Comment: Do not edit SOLVED into questions. Answers belong **only** in the answer section; they should never be added to a question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`less` only mediates between its stdin and a terminal *when its output is connected to a terminal*; when you connect its output to the input of another command (like `tee`), there's no terminal for it to communicate with.

---

In the general case, `tee` belongs **before** `less` in your pipeline, not after it: `less` needs to be the last thing before the terminal to operate as intended, because its purpose *is to feed content to a terminal in a user-friendly way*; it doesn't make sense to page to a file, because files don't have a screen that someone wants to scroll around it.

---

If your specific purpose is to log *exactly what was and wasn't read by the user at the terminal* (potentially as well as timings, input, etc depending on optional arguments added), use `script` instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

tryit()
{
    longfile=$(mktemp)
    /bin/ls -R /etc 2>/dev/null >"$longfile"

    less -R "$longfile"
}

export -f tryit
script SOME_LOGFILE bash -c tryit
```

Comment: That worked - thanks.  I also found that "unbuffer -p less ..." fixed the problem.

Comment: _nod_ -- `unbuffer` emulates a terminal, so it _will_ work in practice. I tend to prefer suggesting a built-to-purpose tool rather than something that works as a side effect, hence `script`.